How to convert a positive integer to binary inside mongoDB aggregation
I was looking for a way to convert a positive integer into a binary array inside a mongoDB aggregation pipeline.
There is $bit operation which can't be used inside an aggregation pipeline.
This question is regarding mongoDB version 6.0 and older
Input example data:
[
  {_id: 1, integerInput: 13},
  {_id: 2, integerInput: 3 },
  {_id: 3, integerInput: 1 },
  {_id: 4, integerInput: 17},
  {_id: 5, integerInput: 10}
]

Requested output:
[
  {_id: 1, integerInput: 13, binary: [1, 1, 0, 1]},
  {_id: 2, integerInput: 3 , binary: [1, 1]},
  {_id: 3, integerInput: 1 , binary: [1]},
  {_id: 4, integerInput: 17, binary: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]},
  {_id: 5, integerInput: 10, binary: [1, 0, 1, 0]}
]


Binary functions in Aggregation Framework are very limited. Performance wise this one should be better:
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         binary: {
            $function: {
               body: function (val) {
                  return val.toString(2).split('').map(x => parseInt(x));
               },
               args: ["$integerInput"],
               lang: "js"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])


I ran the two answers above.

mongod is v6.0.4
1,000,000 docs.   integerInput is a rand between 1 and 32000.
Machine is MacBook M2 Max, 64GB, Sonoma 14.3.

Using @nimrod solution (no functions):
read 1000000; 16193 millis to run; 61755 r/sec
Using @wernfried solution (with $function):
read 1000000; 25216 millis to run; 39657 r/sec
$function takes it toll....

One option is to do the calculation using $map with $range and $log operations:
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      binary: {$reverseArray: {
          $map: {
            input: {$concatArrays: [
                [0],
                {$range: [1, {$ceil: {$log: ["$integerInput", 2]}}]}
            ]},
            in: {$mod: [
                {$floor: {$divide: [
                      "$integerInput",
                      {$pow: [2, "$$this"]}
                ]}},
                2
            ]}
          }
      }}
  }}
])

See How it works on the mongoDB playground

That will only work for positive integers though.

@RobbyCornelissen, you are absolutely right. I updated the question so it will be clear
